# counting the distinct values of: a column A and the pair of columns (A,B)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, oracle12c

suppose we have the following data:

```
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | user_code | order_id | line_id |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | ezz       | 1        | 1       |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | ezz       | 1        | 2       |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | ezz       | 1        | 2       |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | ezz       | 2        | 1       |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | ezz       | 2        | 2       |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | ezz       | 2        | 2       |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | ezz       | 2        | 2       |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | ezz       | 2        | 3       |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
    | ezz       | 3        | 1       |
    +-----------+----------+---------+
```

for a given `user_code` how can we count the how many ***unique order_id*** it has and how many ***unique pair (order_id, line_id)*** it has?

the desired results should looks like:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| user_code | order_count | order_line_count |
+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| ezz       | 3           | 6                |
+-----------+-------------+------------------+
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Oracle 12c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't support `count(distinct)` with multiple arguments.  You can use string concatenation:

```
select user_code, count(distinct order_id) as num_orders,
       count(distinct order_id || ':' || line_id) as num_order_lines
from t
group by user_code;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
SELECT user_code,
     COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS order_count,
     COUNT(DISTINCT order_id || '^' || line_id) AS order_line_count
                    -- building single value from 2 columns
FROM tab
GROUP BY user_code
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to de-duplicate the data first, then use a count(distinct) and a standard count.

```
select   user_code, count(distinct order_id) as ct_ord_id, 
                    count(line_id)           as ct_line_id
from     (select distinct user_code, order_id, line_id from TABLE_NAME)
group by user_code
;
```